# Why does it seem that my Google Extension begins execution only when I'm observing background script console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like my Google Extension to start execution as soon as Google Chrome window is opened. I have the following code in my background.js :

```
if (window.Notification) {
    setInterval( function() { callAutomate(); }, 60000 );
}

function callAutomate() {
 // Code to automate hello-hello.com
}
```

The manifest file is as follows -

```
{
    "name" : "Hello.co Extension",
    "version" : "1.1",
    "description" : "Say Hello",
    "background" :
    {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "hello-19.png",
        "default_title": "Hello World",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": ["https://www.hellohello.com/*"],    
        "js": [
            "content.js",
            "webDB.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [ 
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "webNavigation",
        "notifications",
        "https://www.hellohello.com/"
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "icons" : {
        "48" : "hello-48.png",
        "128" : "hello-128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "hello-48.png"
    ]
}
```

Here is my problem the callAutomate(); function seems to called only while I'm observing the console logs for background.js. However the expected behavior of the extension is to call the callAutomate(); function every one minute from the time Google Chrome window is opened.

Any help with explanatory code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Chrome extension documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#background_page), there are 2 types of background pages:

- **persistent** background page : always "opened"
- **event** background page : "open and closed" as needed

You are using the second one, as specified with the `"persistent": false` in your manifest.json file,
so the background code will not execute itself when you normally load your page.
And I am pretty sure that when you are using the developer tool ("observing the console") on your background page, the page is "opened" and does not close while the console remains open.

By removing the `"persistent": false` your code will be executed.

But as suggested in the documentation, you should use event pages as much as possible so have a look at the [lifetime documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#lifetime) to see the different ways you can communicate with your background page and thus execute your desired code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate you taking time and explaining this to me.

Answer (score 2):

That is because of `"persistent": false` in the manifest.

This describes an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), that is, a page Chrome can unload at will if it is idle for more than a couple of seconds, only keeping track of registered event handlers.

Notes for Event pages explicitly mention:

> If your extension uses `window.setTimeout()` or `window.setInterval()`, switch to using the alarms API instead. **DOM-based timers won't be honored** if the event page shuts down.

And if you open a Dev Tools window for the background page, it will NOT be unloaded, leading to your code executing properly.

---

You can switch to using [`chrome.alarms` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms), but before you do, **carefully** read the Event page documentation. You need to understand all the limitations: for instance, since the page is unloaded, all local state in variables is lost. If you need to persist state, you'll need to employ storage APIs.

If that is too complicated for your purposes, remove `"persistent": false` to revert to a normal Background page.

Comment: I also thank you for taking time and explaining my short comings.